# Change progress value by clicking a button

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `NgCircleProgressModule` library which allowed me to get a circle and a percentage value in the center.

I understand that the progress value is static and only changes when you click the buttons.

If you click on the 25% button in the center of the circle, the 25% and the same button will appear there.

When I click the button I just have to change this: `[percent] = "25"`, but I don't know how to create the function so that the [percent] gets the value associated with the button

Does anyone know how I can do this?

**HTML**

```
<circle-progress
  [percent]="progress"
  [radius]="100"
  [outerStrokeWidth]="10"
  [innerStrokeWidth]="10"
  [space] = "-10"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#4882c2'"
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#e7e8ea'"
  [titleFontSize]= "24"
  [unitsFontSize]= "24"
  [showSubtitle] = "false"
  [animation]="true"
  [animationDuration]="300"
  [startFromZero]="false"
  [responsive]="true"
></circle-progress>

<button>25%</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this using `(click)` event:

```
<button (click)="progress = 25">25%</button>
```

or,

.html

```
<button (click)="changeProgress(25)">25%</button>
```

.ts

```
changeProgress(value) {
  this.progress = value
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpucld?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you !! It was making a mess and it was that simple. Thanks !

Comment: I would like to suggest you to move setting value of progress variable to method in component.

Comment: @MikeLanders You are welcome. Please accept the answer if this was helpful

Comment: The second turns out to be a better solution, even if you later want to save the values. I already accept the answer, I'm just waiting for the timeout

Comment: Yes, in the 2nd way, you can dynamically set the value based on some event of different function